# How do I update PDF metadata without creating new file?

Tags: pdf, pdfbox

I used [Benubird PDF manager](http://www.debenu.com/products/desktop/debenu-pdf-benubird/) for managing PDFs and update the metadata of PDFs. Now I need to update the metadata of PDFs in bulk. I've checked pdfbox from Apache, pyPDF etc but all the solutions create a new PDF with added metadata. Is there a way to update the PDF metadata without creating the copy, I just want to update the metadata in the original PDF.

Answer (score 0):

Try the [cpdf command line tools](http://community.coherentpdf.com/), which know how to read and write to the same file:

```
cpdf -set-metadata metadata.xml in.pdf -o in.pdf
```